# moving multiple objects from different layers into the same layer? Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, cs6

Is there a way to drag and select over multiple paths/ artwork in illustrator and put them all in one layer instead of going into each layer and shifting? [image]

Comment: Cut, then Paste in front

Answer (score 1):

Unless Adobe's recently changed things...

**Layer Panel** menu -> **Flatten Artwork**.

Note that "flatten" in this instance does **not** refer to flattening transparent objects. In fact the use of "flatten" here has *nothing* to do with any object appearance. It *purely* means "combine all layers into one" i.e. flatten the *layer stack* **not** the artwork.

I've set the objects in the animation below to have a fill set to 50% opacity. You can see in the animation, these fills are **not** altered in any way. The *only* thing which occurs is the layers are all combined to a single layer.

CS6 animation...

[image]

<sub>(If they haven't already done so, Adobe *really* should change the menu item wording. Current wording is entirely misleading. In fact, it *should* have been changed when Illustrator v10, which introduced transparency, was released back in 2001.)</sub>